# The use of a pointer to an unnamed struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

What's the use for something like

```
typedef struct
{
    int field_1;
    float field_2;
}*T;
```

in `C` ?

Since a `struct` is a datatype in `C`, where the information about the datatype pointed by `T` is stored and how to correctly initialize a variable `var` that is declared as `T var` ?

Comment: `T var = malloc(sizeof(*var))`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan is this valid standard `C` syntax ? looks like a workaround; I have never seen this before .

Comment: The syntax is valid (otherwise the program wouldn't compile :) ) And it might be a workaround of sorts (see my answer)

Comment: @Ashalynd most of the time even code that shows signs of undefined behaviour compiles, I'm asking because it's the first time I have ever seen this kind of syntax, I can't imagine a real valid use for that at the point where this is a good / only way to code.

Comment: Where did you encounter it? May be if you provide more background you will get a better answer.

Comment: @user2485710 [what I means](http://codepad.org/mIedMl1L)

Comment: @Ashalynd just hacking around, I'm trying to get how Objective C internally works by playing with C, now the real thing is to find a practical use for this, not so much how to understand how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` is an *alias* for a pointer to the structure. The structure itself is not a type, but `T` is.

`T` is not stored anywhere but in the compilers internal tables for types.

You can use it like

```
T myVariable = malloc(sizeof(*myVariable));
```

Comment: There are applications or scenario where this is useful or it's the only viable way ?

Answer (score 1):

The use is as if the struct was named. I.e. you can access struct fields via this pointer. For example:

```
void fun(T p) {
   if (p->field_1 == 0) p->field_2 = 1.2345;
}
```

If you never need to reference a structure itself by a name, there is no need to give it one. The info about structure (and its members) is stored in compiler tables in the same way as for named structures.

This construct is useful in defining complex data structures (possibly with unions) and not to pollute global name space with useless names. For example:

```
 struct myUsefulStructure {
    int stype;
    union {
       struct {  // a structure which is never referenced itself
          ...
       } x;
       struct {  // another structure which is never referenced itself
          ...
       } y;
    } u;
  };
```

Comment: If you know you will never need a variable of this (sub)structure type then you do not need to invent a name for it and to risk it may clash with some other existing structure name.

Comment: @user2485710 Union is way to reuse the same place for multiple data. If you use a union, usually it is composed of structures. Usually those structures are not used elsewhere. There is no trick, it is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like that (pointer-to-unnamed-struct) to be used in order to describe the data which are coming from outside of the program in question (e.g. given as a return value from a library function, when it is allocated and deallocated by that library). Then such typedef is just a specification how to access these data.