# What does this pointer of type structure definition mean (in C)?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dereference, anonymous-struct

In K&R Chapter 6, a declaration is mentioned as follows:

```
struct{
    int len;
    char *str;
} *p;
```

I couldn't understand which structure is this pointer p pointing to and if such a pointer definition is even valid because in all other examples given in the book and the ones I have seen otherwise, when defining a pointer to a structure, the name of the structure, that is, the type being defined needs to be mentioned. For example,

```
struct example{
    int a;
    ...
}s1;
```

and then,

```
struct example *ptr = &s1;
```

so, it is mentioned that ptr is pointing to a type struct example and not just struct.

Also, of particular interest was this:

> *p->str fetches whatever str points to; *p->str++
>   increments str after accessing whatever it points to (just like *s++);

I couldn't follow what p is in the first place, hence, not the increment and dereference as well.

What is going on here?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am new here, so any feedback on the format of the question would also be appreciated.

Comment: In the first example the structure is an *anonymous* structure, and `p` is a pointer to that anonymous structure.

Comment: What's an anonymous structure? Is it a kind of structure or are you referring to the the fact that the structure type is undefined?

Comment: It's just a structure that has no name, like the one shown. It's not used very often, because it's of limited use.

Comment: It's a structure type with no name, so you can't declare any other variables with the same structure type.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I missed that; made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The use of a pointer to an unnamed struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117726/the-use-of-a-pointer-to-an-unnamed-struct-in-c)

Comment: @RaymondChen Apparently that question is not really about anonymous structures, but about a pointer *type* rather than just a pointer to such.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But as part of the set-up for that question, it answer the question about "What does this tagless struct syntax mean?"

Comment: you should select one of the answers if it is to your satisfaction

Comment: Was it correct of me to tag this [tag:anonymous-struct] ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `struct` keyword works sort of like an extended version of `typedef`, except that you create a complex custom type (called a structure) instead of aliasing an existing type. If you only have one thing that needs to use the declared type, you do not need to provide an explicit name for the type.

The first statement you are looking at declares a structure with two fields, but does not name it. This is called an anonymous structure. The declaration does, however, provide a pointer of that type.

One possible use-case for such a declaration is when you make a header for an external library, possibly one that is not even written in C. In that case, the type of the structure may be opaque or incomplete, and you just need to have a convenient reference to some parts of it. Making the structure anonymous prevents you from being able to allocate it yourself easily, but allows you to interact with it through the pointer.

More commonly, you will see this notation used in conjunction with named or at least aliased structures. The second statement could be rewritten as

```
struct example { ... } s1, *ptr;
```

In that case, `struct example *ptr = &s1;` would be just `ptr = &s1;`.

An even more common occurrence is the use of anonymous structures with `typedef`, create custom type names that do not include the `struct` keyword. Your second example could be rewritten as

```
typedef struct { ... } example, *pexample;
example s1;
pexample ptr; // alternatively example *ptr;
ptr = &s1;
```

Note that the type of `s1` is `example` and not `struct example` in this case.

Comment: Should the phrase "provide a pointer *to* that type" be more accurately written, "provide a pointer *of* that type"?  I misread your answer to mean that we had a pointer to the type itself.

Comment: @Dan. Fixed. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 3):

For starters consider the following simple program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(void) 
{
    struct {
        int len;
        char *str;
    } *p;

    p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );

    p->str = "Hello Nihal Jain";
    p->len = strlen( p->str );

    while ( *p->str ) putchar( *p->str++ );
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello Nihal Jain
```

So in this declaration

```
    struct {
        int len;
        char *str;
    } *p;
```

there is declared a pointer of the type of the unnamed structure. The pointer itself is not initialized. You could write for example

```
    struct {
        int len;
        char *str;
    } *p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
```

For this simple program the name of the structure is not required because neither declaration of an object of the structure type is present or needed in the program.

So you can not declare an object of the structure type but it is not required in this case.

According to the C Standard structure or union are declared like

```
struct-or-union-specifier:
    struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
    struct-or-union identifier
```

It is seen that the identifier is optional if there is a struct-declaration-list. So an unnamed structure can be used as a type specifier.

One more example with using enumerations. You can declare enumerators without declaring the enumeration type. For example

```
enum { EXIT_SUCCESS = 0, EXIT_FAILURE = -1 };
```

You can use the enumerators that have the type `int` without declaring an object of the enumeration type if there is no such a requirement in the program.

Comment: TIL you could still extract the size via `sizeof(*p)`. Very +1.

Comment: @MadPhysicist or `sizeof *p`.  `()` not needed.  (A style issue)

Comment: @chux. Point taken. I just happen to prefer putting parentheses everywhere.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You may enjoy [`(LISP)`](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/lisp_cycles.png).

Comment: The string is not allocated so how could that work? I think there should be a warning to that code usage in dealing with a uninitialized pointer to char on the LHS expression with a constant string used as RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Also another use (of anonymous structures) would be to use them inside unions or other structs which basically limits the use of that struct to that particular parents union or structure not anything else, which is quite useful from programmer's point of view because looking at a code like this it provides us with the information that it is used locally on the context of the struct or union inside it -
 nothing more than that. (also saves us from naming).

---

Also if you use this anonymous structure you wont be able to allocate one instance of it other than the one which already exists.

Example:-(stark's comment: how to use it?)

```
struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} p;

scanf("%d",&p.a);
```

Comment: Or accidentally allocating one of our own.

Comment: @MadPhysicist.: Yes true.you cant allocate when it's anonymous...just like one time use...

Comment: How would you refer to the anon struct elements?

Comment: @stark.: Like this

Comment: @coderredoc `p=malloc(sizeof(*p))`. (It's in the original case of `p` being pointer).. **update** - oh, I see it is mentioned in the other answer..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It is just an example for the user to get the example. If there is any error let me know..and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed an ad-hoc, one-time-use definition of a struct (or union) that will not be useful outside of scope in which it was declared, you would use what is called [anonymous or unnamed structs and unions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html). This saves you from having to declare the struct before you use it and, in the case of complex types, declaring the inner types, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361366/4454124).